Blank page after update
I'm very late with updates. Currently V 5.50.2. I'm trying to catch up. I tried installing several newer versions. The installation of the files goes without problems. But when updating the database, nothing happens: blank page! same in admin: no acces
Thank you for your help
log
Jul 03 23:22:04  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/gami5610/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(441): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/gami5610/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Core_Exception))
#2 /home/gami5610/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#3 /home/gami5610/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(11): civicrm_invoke()
#4 /home/gami5610/public_html/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(402): require_once("/home/gami5610/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
#5 /home/gami5610/public_html/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(377): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/gami5610/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
#6 /home/gami5610/public_html/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php(194): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
#7 /home/gami5610/public_html/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php(233): Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->dispatch()
#8 /home/gami5610/public_html/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php(225): Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->doExecute()
#9 /home/gami5610/public_html/index.php(49): Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
#10 {main
